# How to disable to turn off audio sound by clicking up-down buttons on the side of a phone?

Tags: android, audio

I want to start an alarm for some case. Once alarm starts, turning off the alarm with using up-down buttons must be blocked. 
I find some code but it doesn't work.

```
AudioManager am =(AudioManager) ctxt.getSystemService(ctxt.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
                0);
        am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
```

Edit: Only `setStremMute` part dosen't work and there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the volume up and down key events in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            // Ignore
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            // Ignore
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it will be easy question but how can I make free these buttons, after the alarm stop?

Comment: This alarm is being handled entirely within your application, right? So you should have control whether user has dismissed it and stop ignoring the keys. You could use some sort of state flag.